# what happens with Get/Transform connections when openening in excel 2010 without the Powerquery add onn

Tags: excel, powerquery

When creating a workbook in Excel 2016, with connections to a table in another tab I've used the Get/Transform or PowerQuery function. It's standard provided in Excel 2016.
Do you know what consequences are when I would open such a workbook in a 2010/2013 version where the PowerQuery add on is not installed?
Thanks

Comment: Basically, users will see pivot tables, but they can’t use filters/slicers etc. excel will throw an error. Pretty useless approach. It just becomes static report

Comment: Ah thanks. Would you know this: I've created a table1 in tab1, created a Get/Transform/ Powerquery in Tab2 based on Table1, but filtered. Would you know what would happen to this workbook in 2010/2013 without PowerQuery addon?

Comment: Tables are tables, normal behavior . The only thing refresh wouldn’t work, beside that you can add columns with formulas, etc...